# SQL identity (1,1) starting at 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, identity, dbcc

I have a SQL table with an identity set:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable(
    MyTableID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    RecordName nvarchar(100) NULL)
```

Something has happened to this table, resulting in odd behaviour. I need to find out what.

When an insert occurs:

```
INSERT MyTable(RecordName) 
VALUES('Test Bug')

SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() -- returns 0
SELECT * FROM MyTable   -- displays: 0, 'Test Bug'
```

This is a problem because code above this insert expects the first ID to be `1` - I can't figure out how with `IDENTITY(1,1)` this ends up as `0`.

If (before executing the `INSERT`) I check the identity it returns null:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT (MyTable, NORESEED)
```

> Checking identity information: current identity value 'NULL', current column value 'NULL'.

I know several ways to fix this; what I need to know how the table got into this state in the first place?

The only way I know that `CHECKIDENT` returns null is if the table's just been created, but then `IDENTITY(1,1)` is honoured and the `INSERT` causes `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` to be `1`.

Alternatively I can get `0` as the next ID if I force `-1` as the current seed (`DBCC CHECKIDENT (MyTable, RESEED, -1)` or with `SET IDENTITY_INSERT MyTable ON`) but then the check reports that current `-1` seed (rather than null), so that can't be what's happened.

How did the database get into a state where the column has `IDENTITY(1,1)`, `DBCC CHECKIDENT (MyTable, NORESEED)` returns null, but the next `INSERT` causes `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` to be `0`?

Comment: I assume there is a trigger on table `MyTable`.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan There are no triggers on that table.

Comment: Have you achieve the same result when you recreate the table?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan no, that's what I'm asking - I know the state the table's ended up in, I need to know how it got into that state.

Comment: If you care about the numerical values of identity columns, you're using them wrong. All you should know is a) that they uniquely identify each row, and b) that you can *store* them in numeric columns.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever we have an optimisation in code where IDs must be `>=1` before the overhead of a DB call is made. This helped us avoid an N+1 issue in a large amount of legacy code. If this was in a code base that we were writing from scratch this would be easy to avoid.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I expect someone/something has run:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('dbo.MyTable', RESEED, 0);
```

If you run the following:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable(
    MyTableID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    RecordName nvarchar(100) NULL
);

DBCC CHECKIDENT ('dbo.MyTable', RESEED, 0);
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('dbo.MyTable', NORESEED);
```

The second `CHECKIDENT` still returns `NULL`:

> Checking identity information: current identity value 'NULL', current column value 'NULL'.

However the next identity value will be 0. This is [documented behaviour](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258817%28SQL.80%29.aspx), MSDN states:

> The current identity value is set to the new_reseed_value. **If no rows have been inserted to the table since it was created, the first row inserted after executing DBCC CHECKIDENT will use new_reseed_value as the identity**. Otherwise, the next row inserted will use new_reseed_value + 1. If the value of new_reseed_value is less than the maximum value in the identity column, error message 2627 will be generated on subsequent references to the table.

This only works on newly created/truncated tables where the `last_value` column in `sys.identity_columns` is still NULL. As described above if you were to insert a row, delete it, then reseed to 0, the new identity would still be 1.

**Full Test Script**

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.T', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE dbo.T;

CREATE TABLE dbo.T(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL);
INSERT dbo.T OUTPUT inserted.* DEFAULT VALUES;
-- OUTPUTS 1

DELETE dbo.T;
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('dbo.T', RESEED, 0);
INSERT dbo.T OUTPUT inserted.* DEFAULT VALUES;
-- OUTPUTS 1

TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.T;
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('dbo.T', RESEED, 0);
INSERT dbo.T OUTPUT inserted.* DEFAULT VALUES;
-- OUTPUTS 0
```

Comment: Cheers! That was the problem - someone had called `DBCC CHECKIDENT (MyTable, RESEED, 0)` when they should have called `DBCC CHECKIDENT (MyTable, RESEED)`. I had no idea that still reported null as the current ident if the table had never been populated.

Comment: @Keith  Did you mean to say that they should have called `DBCC CHECKIDENT (MyTable, NORESEED)`?